# how to edit the signal name of scope?

Tags: oscilloscope, matlab, simulink

I used the Using the PLECS Scope to edit the scope but when it comes to the name of the signal I could not change even though I double-click on it and tries many times, is there any way to change the signal name?

[image]

best regards,

Comment: actually I double click after right click

Comment: VTC - This question has nothing to do with electronics design as defined for the scope of this site.

Comment: where can I post, please?

Comment: What is **PLECS Scope** ? If you use normal scope you can simply right click on the scope and name the signal. I couldn't find any block named **PLECS Scope**!